# Overwrite not working as expected

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides

I am trying to display a message in template when there are no viewed_products. So I have tried to overwrite class Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed and its method like this.

**Module etc/config.xml file**

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <reports>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_viewed>Myclass_Overwrites_Block_Reports_Product_Viewed</product_viewed>
                </rewrite>
            </reports>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Block in app/code/local/Myclass/Overwrites/Block/Product/Viewed.php**

```
class Myclass_Overwrites_Block_Reports_Product_Viewed extends Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed
  {
    ...

      protected function _toHtml(){

             if ($this->getCount()) {
               $this->setRecentlyViewedProducts($this->getItemsCollection());
             }
         return parent::_toHtml();
       }
...
  }
```

Now it overwrites it, if i click on a product and refresh the page i can clearly see with debuging ON that its getting overwritten and that product is shown. But if i don't click on a product (if visited product/s arent stored) it doesnt show anything (i guess it runs the class from Core, i also tried to change it just to see if it would work in core files and it does). I am doing this because i want to show else statement from template

**Template design/frontend/Project/default/template/reports/product_viewed.phtml**

```
 <?php if ($_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()): ?>

 //Code if there are Viewed Products

 <?php else: ?> // This doesn't show
   <div class="block block-list block-viewed row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="block-title panel-heading">
    <h3 class ="panel-title"><span><?php echo $this->__('Recently Viewed Products') ?></span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content panel-body">
      <p>You haven't viewed any Products</p>
     </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Am i doing something wrong or could i do this some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havent figured out how to display Recently viewed products if the user didnt click on any product. So i have left it by defualt to not show.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow bellow steps:

**Module etc/config.xml file**

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <reports>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_viewed>Myclass_Overwrites_Block_Reports_Product_Viewed</product_viewed>
                </rewrite>
            </reports>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**created block in app/code/local/Myclass/Overwrites/Product/Viewed.php**
**> and a class has to be defined**

```
class Myclass_Overwrites_Block_Reports_Product_Viewed extends Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed
{
// some code
}
```

Comment: I have it like that, thanks for the help.Perhaps i should have wrote everything i will edit it. It works when user clicked on a product and then i can see it beeing overwritten, but my problem is when user didnt click on any product it doesnt show nothing only when i put it in Core

Comment: can you please send your code or url?

Comment: I have edited in my post what i have changed or added in each file. Sadly i only have it local. And also if i was unclear about debug i turned Template Path Hints and Add Block Names to Hints. And as i said with them if i click on a random product i see that product in product_viewed and i see my overwritten class. but if i delete history and reload page i cant see the else statement from template (but if i do this directly in core it works). Somehow if it is empty it wont overwrite

Comment: Okay let me try and give reply you :)

Comment: Thank you :), The main problem is when there are no viewed_products i would like to display in template a message, maybe i could do that some other way?